# Laravel issue uploading large files to external disk (S3)

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, php-7, plesk

I'm having issues uploading files with the size of about 400MB to an external disk in Laravel.
On the local disk I have no issues storing the uploaded file but when it needs to be uploaded to the S3 disk I get the following error:

```
ErrorException: fwrite(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory.
```

The following code is used (which gives no errors):

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$local = \Storage::disk('local');
$local->put($desitinationUrl,  $contents);
```

But when the following happens I get an error

```
$uploadedfile = \Storage::disk('local')->get($destinationUrl);
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->put($destinationUrl,  $uploadedfile);
```

Does anyone know where the issue may be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the same problem with small files? It would be very useful to understand if it only occurs past a certain size or if size doesn't matter

Comment: Small files are no issue, I can upload up to about 250MB via this way, but larger than that I get this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try directly writing the stream as you read it:

```php
Storage::disk('s3')
  ->writeStream(
      $destinationUrl, 
      Storage::disk('local')->readStream($destinationUrl)
  );
```